# flutter: running pod install takes forever while building in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods, ios14

Using iphone 11 iOS-14 device and simulator, I have deleted THE podfile and podlock of my flutter app and trying to rebuild the app in debug MODE, i am using the latest firebase dependencies including cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1 dependency then it gets stuck at pod install and is taking forever to finish, been more than half an hour.

I wonder if i should wait longer or is there something wrong with firebase dependencies?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pod install is not stuck, when you delete Podfile.lock, pod install will redownload all pod dependencies, will take a long time, after finish, it will create a new Podfile.lock

I have a project that have 20+ dependencies for flutter, firebase dependencies are the most complex ones

Comment: i have 19 dependencies including most of firebase.. i hope it gets to an end, it wouldnt take this long with older depedencies especially firebase ones

Comment: It is expected, when I make the mistake of deleting podfile.lock I have to wait about 3/4+ hours, just let it do the job, take a coffe, play some games, when you comeback it will succeed.

Comment: if you confirm that this worked, don't forget to mark as accepted answer

Comment: don't worry i will, still waiting for now

Comment: yup, I can confirm, it doesn't stuck. it takes almost 1 hour for me to eventually run the app. crazy

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it seems that the 'pod install' command is taking forever, but it is downloading the dependencies in the background.

Please try to look into the Activity Monitor network tab to confirm that some data is being downloaded.

In my case, my pod depended on the Firebase pods, so it took around 10 minutes to complete my dependencies.

Comment: Where can we acivate the Activity Monitor network tab ?

Comment: @EkimCemÜlger This specifically for macOS, but open the "Activity Monitor" app. Then, on the top of the window for this app you'll see the "Network" tab, to the right of "Disk". Look for Process Name of "git-remote-https".

Answer (score 1):

If you have spent 20-30 minutes of your time holding onto pod install and yet it seems to stuck forever (Possibly installed firebase dependencies then running same project on different machine). Then there are other workaround to it.

Clean cache and pub get your dependencies

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Navigate to your ios folder from the terminal

```
cd ios
```

Remove Trunk

```
pod repo remove trunk
```

If your current installation is in Intel Chipped Mac run the code below

```
pod install --repo-update
```

If your installation is in M1 chip device install ffi first

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then update POD

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Now clean and fetch dependencies

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

If you encountered an error similar to like below

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Then go to podfile, uncomment platmform:ios line and update it

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Now re-run the command

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Don't Forget to clean pub caches with flutter clean

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way on their official documentation is as follow:

> Optional: Improve iOS & macOS build times by including the pre-compiled framework.
> Currently, the Firestore SDK for iOS depends on code that can take upwards of 5 minutes to build in Xcode. To reduce build times significantly, you can use a pre-compiled version by adding this line to the target 'Runner' do block in your Podfile:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  # ...
end
```

Additionally, ensure that you have upgraded CocoaPods to 1.9.1 or higher:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line under **target 'Runner' do** in Podfile.

> pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git =>
> 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag
> => '6.33.0'

Then in IOS:

```
flutter clean
pod repo update
```

For more info: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2751

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Xcode is up to date.
Updating my Xcode has resolved the issue for me.

I have tried all the above solutions but non have worked.
Only updating Xcode has worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

previous comment was correct, you need just wait in
"Running pod install..." and "Running Xcode building..."
i attached the screen, how long i waited, there you can find:

1. Running pod install... **687.5s(11.4 mins)**
2. Running Xcode building... **1421.2s(23.6 mins)**

i hope this help to someone like proof ))

i didn't adding this one:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  # ...
end
```

maybe it will be faster, also was commented it:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

1. **cd ios**
2. **pod cache clean --all**
3. **pod clean**
4. **pod deintegrate**
   [pod deintegrate result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0z5m.png)
5. **sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean**
   [cocoa deintegrate result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvCdI.png)
6. **sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**
   [ffi result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UesPl.png)
7. **arch -x86_64 pod repo update**
   [pod repo update result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYflg.png)
8. **gem install cocoapods**
   [cocoapods install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh0oK.png)
9. **arch -x86_64 pod install** (Make sure internet connectivity here)